# React-slick slider not rendering on jsdom

Tags: reactjs, jsdom

I'm using jsdom to render my react components , one of the components being a react-slick slider, so this slider is not being rendered correctly on the server.

The code is as follows:

```
class GallerySlider extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    let { children, initialSlide, afterChange } = this.props;
    const LeftNav = <Icon color="white" name="arrow-left" />;
    const RightNav = <Icon color="white" name="arrow-right" />;

    let settings = {
      accessibility: true,
      adaptiveHeight: false,
      autoplay: false,
      className: "media-gallery__gallery--slider",
      dots: false,
      //infinite: false, // Currently doesn't work in combination with lazyload. Should turn-off when fixed.
      lazyLoad: true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      speed: 250,
      prevArrow: LeftNav,
      nextArrow: RightNav,
      initialSlide: initialSlide || 0,
      afterChange: afterChange
    };

    return (
      <div className="media-gallery__gallery-slider">
        <Slider ref="slider" {...settings}>
          {children}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GallerySlider;
```

It looks like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZE73.png)

The code rendered is as follows:
[code_rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OUwv.png)
Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: No I think you should set it in css. Try this: `.slick-slide { height: 500px; }`

Comment: Hey that fix also doesn't seem to work. :(

Comment: Hmm, what is in the `media-gallery__gallery--slider` class?

Comment: just min-height: 60vh;

Comment: `.slick-slide { width: 100%; }`

Comment: @Jurrian this won't work because somehow there is an inline width added which is 0

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example? [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/)

Comment: I'm afraid i can't do so since it's too complicated to be replicated

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the [docs](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick):

⚠️ Also install slick-carousel for css and font

```
npm install slick-carousel

// Import css files
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

or add cdn link in your html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="UTF-8" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
```

Comment: Still no luck :(